# Finite order function in the complex analysis.

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, self-learning, harmonic-functions

Assume that an entire function $f$ be finite order with finitely many zeros.

Please show that either $f(z)$ is a polynomial or $f(z) + z$ has infinitely many zeros.

Thank you.

---

And I know the following theorem,

Suppose f is entire function of finite order. Then either f has infinitely many zeros or $f(z)$ is of the form $Q(z)e^{P(z)}$ for polynomials $P$ and $Q$.

---

Comment: Hint: Does $f(z)+z$ have finite order?  Does $f(z)+z$ have the form $Q(z)e^{P(z)}$?

Comment: Can you write this more explicitly? By assuming that $f(z)+z$ has finitely many zeros, I'll get a condtradiction. Should I prove so? If so, can you show this proof? Thank you. @AntonioVargas

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finite order is not needed.  Apply Picard's  "big" theorem to $f(z)/z$.

Comment: $f(z)/z$ has an essential singularity at $\infty$.  The theorem then says that with at most one exception, $f(z)/z$ takes every complex value infinitely many times.  But by assumption $0$ is that exception, so $-1$ is not...

Comment: Why $f(z)/z$ has an essential singularity at $\infty$ and not a pole ?

Comment: @boris: A meromorphic function on the Riemann sphere is a rational function.